# How to group stacked barplots? (use same label for several stacked barplots)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data structured like below. What I want is to create stacked barplots per individual and only show the x label grouped. However, in my attempt it repeats the group label for every individual:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Group':["A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D"],
         'Individual':["ind1","ind2","ind3","ind4","ind5","ind6","ind7","ind8"],
         'Component1':list(np.random.random(8)),
         'Component2':list(np.random.random(8)),
         'Component3':list(np.random.random(8)),
         'Component4':list(np.random.random(8))
        })

df.plot(x="Group", y=["Component1","Component2","Component3","Component4"], kind="barh", 
                  stacked=True,  legend=None, width=1, xlabel="")
```

This is the [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrSi8.png) with stacked barplots repeating the group label

[image: 1]

And this is how I would like them:

[image: stacked barplot separated by group label]

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate the bounds between the groups via `np.where`. Appending 0 and the array length take care of the left and right bounds. These can be used to draw horizontal lines and center the labels:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Group': ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D"],
     'Individual': ["ind1", "ind2", "ind3", "ind4", "ind5", "ind6", "ind7", "ind8"],
     'Component1': list(np.random.random(8)),
     'Component2': list(np.random.random(8)),
     'Component3': list(np.random.random(8)),
     'Component4': list(np.random.random(8))
     })
ax = df.plot(x="Group", y=["Component1", "Component2", "Component3", "Component4"], kind="barh",
             stacked=True, legend=None, width=1, xlabel="", color=plt.cm.Set3.colors)

a = df['Group'].values
bounds = np.concatenate([[0], np.where(a[:-1] != a[1:])[0] + 1, [len(a)]])
ax.set_yticklabels([])
for b in bounds - 0.5:
    ax.axhline(b, -0.06, 1, color='navy', ls='--', clip_on=False)
for b0, b1, label in zip(bounds[:-1] - 0.5, bounds[1:] - 0.5, a[bounds[1:] - 1]):
    ax.text(-0.03, (b0 + b1) / 2, label, ha='right', va='center', size=14, transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform())
for spine in ax.spines:
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)  # hide the spines
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, len(a) - 0.5)  # no empty space at top and bottom
plt.show()
```

[image: horizontal barplot with grouped labels]